# vuedraggable : Dynamic categories | Can't drag to a category that has no corresponding item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, draggable, vuedraggable

I have 2 dynamic array of objects. 1 is for `status` and 1 is for `tickets`.

The object's contents are:

```
//Status object | status_list    
[
 {id: 1, name: 'UN ASSIGNED'},
 {id: 2, name: 'TO DO'},
 {id: 3, name: 'IN PROGRESS'},
 {id: 4, name: 'DONE'}
]

//Tickets object | tickets_array
[
 {status_id: 1, data:{id: 1, name: 'Ticket 1', stat_id: 1} },
 {status_id: 1, data:{id: 3, name: 'Ticket 3', stat_id: 1} },
 {status_id: 2, data:{id: 6, name: 'Ticket 6', stat_id: 2} }
]
```

So the UI goes like this...

```
| UN ASSIGNED |   |   TO DO   |   |  IN PROGRESS  |   |   DONE   |
---------------   -------------   -----------------   ------------
|   TICKET 1  |   | TICKET 6  |   |               |   |          |
|   TICKET 1  |   |           |   |               |   |          |
|             |   |           |   |               |   |          |
```

Now, I can drag freely from `UN ASSIGNED` to `TO DO` and likewise. However, I cannot drag anything into `IN PROGRESS` and `DONE`. The reason is that the `<draggable>` component has a property called `:list="ticket_array"` and we know that the id of `IN PROGRESS` and `DONE` does not exist in `ticket_array`.

Here's how I rendered it...

```
<div v-for="(status, index) in status_list" :key="index">
    <div class="status_box_content">
        <div class="status_box_header">
            <h2 dir="auto">{{status.name}}</h2>
                <div class="_draggable">
                    <div v-for="(cated_tix, index2) in tickets_array" :key="index2">
                        <template v-if="index == index2 && cated_tix.status_id == status.id">
                            <draggable class="dragArea" :list="list_array[index].data" group="people" @change="_transferTickets">
                                <vs-card v-for="(tix,tix_index) in cated_tix.data" :key="tix.id">
                                    {{tix.name}}
                                </vs-card>
                            </draggable>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ofcourse there are no problems in rendering, but the problem is I cannot drag anything to the empty categories. Anyone?

Comment: ` <draggable class="dragArea" :list="list_array[index].data"`
Should be ` <draggable class="dragArea" :list="tickets_array[index].data"` ?

Comment: @foxiris It's just a sample name, I forgot to change it :) .
I found the solution tho. Thanks anyways.